# how to make script with grep --include multi file extension

Tags: sh

myScript.sh:

```
grep --color -rn --include=*."$1" "$2" "$3"
```

command:

```
./myScript.sh java keyword .              # it works!
./myScript.sh java,xml keyword .          # it doesn't..
./myScript.sh {java,xml} keyword .        # it doesn't..
./myScript.sh "{java,xml}" keyword .      # it doesn't..
./myScript.sh '{java,xml}' keyword .      # it doesn't..
grep -rn --include=*.{java,xml} keyword . # of course it works
```

How do I command?
or how do I edit myScript so that it can work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples, `{java,xml}` argument gets [expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) by your shell into two parameters `java xml` before it hits your script (which makes your `$1` just `java`, and messes up your parameter numbering with `$2` being `xml`, `$3` being `keyword`).

In my hurried and untested first attempt at answering, I forgot one crucial bit: brace expansion goes first, before variable expansion, so when your variable `$1` is substituted, the brace doesn't get another look.

The only way I found to get around that is using `eval`:

```
eval grep --color -rn --include=*."$1" "$2" "$3"
```

and calling it with

```
./myScript.sh '{java,xml}' keyword .
```

Or, simplifying a bit,

```
eval grep --color -rn --include=*."{$1}" "$2" "$3"
```

and calling with

```
./myScript.sh java,xml keyword .
```

Comment: Thanks for kind explanation, but `./myScript.sh '{java,xml}' keyword .` not works.. The result is the same with `"{java,xml}"`

Comment: Very helpful! but I need to look into brace expansion and var expansion.